# sleep method in java Threads, what does it pause specifically?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, thread-sleep

According to the information I've got so far, I've understood that Thread.sleep() pauses the thread where the method is called. For example, if I call it within the main method it pauses the execution of main. if I call it inside the run of a certain thread, it would only pause that thread.
I need an expertise to confirm my understanding as I feel lost among the too much information on web.
I've been practicing to apply this, throw the following:

a Thread class, Player1:

```
public class Player1 extends Thread{

public void run()
{
   
    try {
        System.out.println("I'm going to sleep");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("I'm awake");
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        
    }
 }
 }
```

a Thread class, Client:

```
   public class Clients extends Thread {

    public void run()
    {   
     printer2(10);
    }

     public synchronized static void printer2(int val)
     {
  
        System.out.println(val);
        System.out.println(val);
        System.out.println(val);
        System.out.println(val);
        System.out.println(val);
        System.out.println(val);

        }
     }
```

they're called inside main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Clients c1 = new Clients(10);
    Player1 p = new Player1();
     p.start();
    c1.start();
    }
```

What happens (according to my understanding): the sleep is applied only to the execution of the player1 thread not to the main thread or the client thread.

Similarly, if I add a sleep method in the run of the Clients thread, it would sleep independently of the other Thread. for instance: this sleeps for its own 1 second and this sleeps for its 1 second as well (even if those 2 1 seconds overlap)

Correct me if I'm wrong please
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is correct, `Thread.sleep(2000);` will only sleep the thread that sleep was called in, however, as you would expect, if one thread was waiting on a result from another thread that was put to sleep then it will also be delayed by the sleeping thread.

Comment: It pauses the current thread. There is no other thread it could possibly pause, as it is a static method.